# NFC distance is too short

Tags: android, nfc

I'm trying to use NFC in my project, I've chosen to work with "Midas NFC" which is a smaller foot print NFC tag.
While I couldn't find any reference regarding the distance it should cover, It seems like NFC should be at least a couple of cm's and at most 10 cm.
What I'm getting with the Midas is just sub mm distance, as I have to place the NFC directly on the NFC sensor on the phone.

I was wondering is there is a way to control the distance on the smartphone side. As sub mm distance is very disappointing.

Hope you guys can share from your experience on working with NFC

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I think the effective distance between nfc reader and tag has several factors.

One is the sensitive of tag reader. Take Android smart phone for example, I've tried several phones, they have different sensitive distance. It depends on their NFC antenna size, antenna material, and chip's calibration value. Metal shell also effect the distance.

The same factors also applied on NFC tag chip. Since your tag Antenna size is fixed. Also your chip has fixed calibration value. Thus it seems nothing can do on the tag.

BTW, the tap motion also effect the distance. NFC using principle of electromagnetic induction, you should tap your tag to phone quickly to increase the distance.

As I know, different tag type has different minimum distance requirement. In NXP 203 tag, it seems sub mm distance is in valid distance.

Comment: Important lesson: do testing against the actual hardware